# Using advanced editing tools say invalid geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile

It says "The Geometry is invalid, please repair before trying to split it". How would I address this issue quickly? I can't cut the certain portion of the poygon whenever I use advanced editing tool such as split feature.

[image]

Comment: What did you try ? Does running the check validity tool in QGIS do anything ?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: I'd tried fixed distance buffer in saga toolbox and after v.clean and also I'd set threshold in both algorithms consistently but still i cant split polygon using advance edit tools. I also tried the check geometries in geometry tools.